# Mysql Indexing For Soft Deletes

Tags: mysql

I have an application which use Ebean ORM for querying the data.

We are using ebean built in feature soft delete to not delete the data permanantly https://ebean.io/docs/features/softdelete

By default this add a column name deleted whose default value is 0 and query for all the columns whose default value is 0. We does not need to query for soft deleted column frequently so shall i add index for this column for all existing indexes so that query become faster?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the "We does not need to query for soft deleted column frequently" AFAIK every time that you will do a select query, the orm will just put in the where clause that you're searching for not soft deleted records.

If this is the case the index IMHO is recommended (obv depending on the size of your db you will need to monitor if you have negative performance hit), if you will always query everything, even deleted (but seems a bit odd), I wouldn't bother

Comment: I am saying i don't have to query deleted column and do queries on only those column who has deleted = 0 so by default all queries have deleted = 0 in where clause like
`select * from table where type = "CLAUSE" and deleted = 0`

So shall i index put index on deleted column